# jquery : why these two lines' execution are executed at the same time?

Tags: jquery

This is my code snippet

```
$(function() {

  $(".red-box").fadeOut(2000); //1
  $(".green-box").fadeOut(2000); //2
  $(".red-box").fadeIn(2000);//3


});
```

index.html is shown below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <title>TProject Structure</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="content">
    <h1>Project Structure</h1>

    <div class="red-box">Red</div>
    <div class="green-box">Green</div>
    <div class="blue-box">Blue</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>

    <h2>Hi, I'm the Base Project!</h2>
    <p>Add elements here as you like to try out jQuery. This is your playground to test out anything that comes into your mind.</p>
    <p><strong>OR:</strong> Copy this project structure into a new directory first to create separate playgrounds for animations, manipulations, event handlers etc.</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I open the HTML page I did notice that

a) First both the red and green box fades out together.
b) Then the red box fades back in.

My Qs

a) How does jQuery know that line 1 and line 2 are to be executed together followed by line 3 ?

If the execution is "line by line" then jQuery should have executed line 1 (i.e wait for 2s before fading out) AND AFTER THAT only should have executed line 2 and so on...

Can someone explain as to why line1 and line2's execution are clubbed together by jQuery ?

Comment: Because as you're calling these functions on _separate objects_ they each go into _separate queues_. When you call it on the _same_ object (like with 3) it adds it to an already existing queue and first begins after the first one has finished. You can use [`jqObject.stop(true)`](https://api.jquery.com/stop/) to clear the queue, if you really want to.

Answer (score 0):

Use call-backs. This should explain: http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/